# Is there a simple way to synchronize Thunderbird across machines?

Tags: sync, thunderbird, email-client

I love Firefox Sync. Is there a similar way to synchronise Thunderbird?

I want to synchronise account settings, filters and address books. I never download e-mails, so this isn't an issue. There is no need to synchronise addons (I don't use Lightning or similar). I don't want an import, but a real synchronisation which reflects a change on all other associated Thunderbird installations. Is there a way to do this (whether automatic or with some tweaking)?

Comment: Well, use a simple backup application like Wuala. Add the folder, set up the sync, that's it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sync Thunderbird across two computers?](http://superuser.com/questions/328091/how-do-i-sync-thunderbird-across-two-computers)

Answer (score 7):

You could use Dropbox and then update the `profiles.ini` file to point to the profile folder in your Dropbox.

```
Windows: %AppData%\Thunderbird
Mac: ~/Library/Thunderbird/
Linux: ~/.thunderbird/
```

See [Thunderbird Profiles](http://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/Profiles) for more information on how to find your profile.

After you copy it to Dropbox then open up the `profiles.ini` file which is located in the same folder and update the `Path` to point to the new location:

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=../../Dropbox/Thunderbird.profile
```

You can of course change the folder name to be whatever you want. I'm not sure how spaces are handled though so you'll have to experiment if you like spaces in your names.

See [Moving a profile](http://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/Profiles#w_moving-a-profile) for some more information and a caveat if you want to use absolute paths instead of relative.

Comment: Will this sync filters too, or only the account settings?

Comment: It will do everything: email and settings. I'm not sure about plugins.

Comment: If one instance of Thunderbird writes there, will other running instances re-read the settings on-the-fly?

Comment: I wish this was part of Thunderbird natively, and my mobile email clients too...

Comment: Alternatively if you don't trust Dropbox you could use a p2p sync like [syncthing](http://syncthing.net/) or [BitTorrent Sync](http://www.getsync.com/)

Comment: I must say that such setup is only giving me trouble even before I tried to stress test the many data corruption hazards. Data loss, plugins disappearing...as much as I love the idea of a "clouded" Thunderbird, it does not handle it well in my experience and will trip over the smallest inconsistency.